# Subtask on Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

Could I do a subtask on Ansible ?
I've tried this but it doesn't work :

```
---
- name: Main_task
  hosts: serv
  tasks:
  - name: Task one
    ....
  - name: Subtasks
    hosts: serv
    tasks:
    - name: Subtask 1
     .....
    - name: Subtask 2
     ....
    with_items:
      - "{{ items_from_task_one }}"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include tasks defined in a file using `include_tasks` ([Ansible Doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html)). Here's a working example:

1. Create a file structure as shown below

   ```
   ├── playbooks
   │   ├── main_task.yml
   │   └── subtasks
   │       ├── subtask_1.yml
   │       └── subtask_2.yml
   ```
2. main_task.yml

   ```
   ---
   - name: Main_task
     hosts: localhost
     tasks:
       - name: Task one
         set_fact:
         items_from_task_one:
           - "value_1"
           - "value_2"

       - name: Include Subtask 1
         include_tasks: ./subtasks/subtask_1.yml
         with_items:
           - "{{ items_from_task_one }}"

       - name: Include Subtask 2
         include_tasks: ./subtasks/subtask_2.yml
         with_items:
           - "{{ items_from_task_one }}"
   ...
   ```
3. subtask_1.yml

   ```
   ---
   - name: Debug message from subtask_1.yml
     debug:
       msg: "I am Subtask 1"

   - name: Debug variable passed by main_task
     debug:
       var: item
   ...
   ```
4. subtask_2.yml

   ```
   ---
   - name: Debug message from subtask_2.yml
     debug:
       msg: "I am Subtask 2"

   - name: Debug variable passed by main_task
     debug:
       var: item
   ...
   ```

Comment: So, I can't do a loop with items_from_task_one if I want to excute in this order : subtask_1 -> subtack_2 -> next_element_of_the_list
and
subtask_1 -> subtack_2 -> next_element_of_the_list
and
....
until the end of the list ?

Comment: Can't think of a way to do it like that. You'd have to merge the relevant tasks in a single subtask if you want those to be performed in sequence.

Comment: Include subtask_1 with a loop from the main playbook then include subtask_2 from subtask_1. But you might as well put all your tasks in the first include. Providing a real life example rather than pseudo-code might help to give a more precise answer and might also rule out a possible [x/y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)